# ITextSharp Image Positioning within Cell

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to offset the position of an image within a table-cell in ITextSharp.  Below is some pseudo-code outlining some of my attempts, none of which seem to affect the positioning of the image.  I'd specifically like to align the middle of the image with the left border of the cell, but I can't even seem to figure out how to move the image at all.

```
doc.Open();
var table = new PdfPTable(1);
var cell = new PdfPCell();
var image = Image.GetInstance(); //etc

image.SetAbsolutePosition(-10, 0); //no effect
image.Left -= 10; //no effect
image.IndentationRight = 10; // no effect

cell.AddElement(image);
table.Rows.Add(new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { cell }));
doc.Add(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding an image to a cell, using an absolute position or changing the properties of the image won't have an effect. If I interpret your question correctly, you want to define a padding for the cell so that there's 10pt of space to the left. Just use the appropriate padding method on the cell object (in iText, that would be `cell.setPaddingLeft(10);`).