# how to change position of added image in pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to change the Image position to be in the top right of the pdf as a logo , this code make my image in the top left and some text wrote on it :

```
string oldFile = @"D:\Source pdf\Source.pdf";
        string newFile = @"D:\Result pdf\Result.pdf";

        string imagepath = @"D:\Source pdf\Myiamge.jpg";
        Console.WriteLine("iText Demo");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
        Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        Document document = new Document(size);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        document.Open();

        iTextSharp.text.Image instanceImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
        document.Add(instanceImg);

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);


        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

        document.Close();
        fs.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150380/itextsharp-image-positioning-within-cell

Comment: Your code is somewhat funny --- you create a new PDF with the image as regular content (therefore typeset with margins) and then stamp a page from some other document on it. You might want to read [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) section 6.3 "Adding content with PdfStamper". The relevant samples StampText and StampStationary for C# can be found [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx). In the former one simply add your image to the canvas instead of applying ColumnText.ShowTextAligned.